# Where does the primal desire come from which animates Pradhana?

Tags: creation, cosmology

In reading an overview of [Hindu Cosmology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_cosmology), I see info about [Pradhana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pradhana):

> Pradhana, which has no consciousness or will to act on its own, is initially agitated by a primal desire to create. The different schools of thought differ in understanding about the ultimate source of that desire and what the gunas are mixed with (eternal elements, time, jiva-atmas).

What are the different school perspectives on the ultimate source of that primal desire? Where does the desire come from, what is it made of?